# bootstrap textarea focus cursor not display in iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, twitter-bootstrap-3, youtube

I have added focus event on `textarea` when bootstrap model open. It works in all browser but focus cursor not displays in iPhone.  focus outline display in iphone textarea but cursor pointer not display.

`$('#bootstrap_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {  $('#textarea').focus(); })`

similar www.m.youtube.com  send feedback focus cursor

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040611/manually-trigger-focus-on-input-iphone-issue not working